# Discrete version of Gauss' Mean Value Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, polygons

I want to prove:

> If $p(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial in complex field and m > degP is an integer, then the arithmetic mean of the values of $p$ at the vertices of any regular m-gon in the complex plane equals the value of $p$ at the center of this m-gon.

My approach is the following:

> Let $p(z) =a_nz^n + ... + a_1z + a_0$, $a_i \neq 0 $, and $m>n$. Let $z_k$, where $k=1,...,m$ be the m many vertices. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{m}p(z_k) = a_n\sum_{k=1}^{m}(z_k)^n +...+a_n\sum_{k=1}^{m}z_k+ma_o $. I consider the vertices in polar form: $z_i = r(cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. Also, consider the center as the origin. Then for each $z_i$ considering $z_j$ as the reflection of $z_i$ with respect to origin,we have $z_j= r(cos(\theta\pm \pi) i\sin(\theta\pm \pi))=-r(cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. For each odd $n$, similarly we can arrive $z_i^n + z_j^n=0$. If we can group the vertices for $n:$even like this, the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{m}p(z_k)$ becomes equal to $ma_0$ and we can get the desired result.

My intuition is that instead of dealing with symmetries with respect to origin, I should be able to write the polar forms of vertices such that using DeMoivre's identity the sum is always $ma_0$. However, I could not find a way to express this in a compact form such as $r(\frac{cos(2k\pi+\theta)}{n}+i\frac{sin(2k\pi+\theta)}{n})$ for some factor $k$.I also feel that this is closely related to the roots of unity expressed in the inscribed unit circle but my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Do you know what an harmonic function is?

Comment: No, when I checked it I couldn't find a relation

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, you do not need harmonic functions. Just find two complex numbers $a$ and $b$ such that the image of the regular polygon $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ is the set of the $m$ roots of unity $1,w=e^{2i\pi/m},\ldots w^{m-1}.$ Taking $0<k<m$ observe that $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}w^{kj}=0.$ To see this, if $r=pgcd(k,m)$ then $w^k$ is root of $z^{m/r}-1$  whose sum of roots is zero. If $k=0$ then $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}w^{kj}=1.$ Therefore, the result is proved in the particular case where $p(z)=z^k$ and the polygon is the polygon of the $m$ roots of unity. Passing from $z^k$ to $p(z)$ is done by linearity. Passing to an arbitrary regular polygon with $m$ vertices is done by the transformation $z\mapsto az+b$ above. The condition $k<m$ is essential, the result for $p(z)=z^m$ is false.